# Swagger Response Attributes for Controller Action Errors

Tags: swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am struggling to find some examples of the `SwaggerResponse` attribute using the controller action errors in my `C#` web api, such as `NotFound()` etc.

I have this attribute on my controller method:

`[SwaggerResponse(404, "Requested application not found", Type = typeof(NotFoundResult))]`

And in the controller method I have this:

`NotFound("No configuration found")`

But in the UI I get this:

[image: 404]

I was hoping it would at least show the code in the json and not `0`?

The only thing that looks reasonable in the UI is the `200` response, which is a `List<settings>` which shows the list, but doesn't show examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finally getting the search terms correct for this I found an answer on here that actually suppresses the error models all together, which is better than having the above in your documentation.

Using `net5.0` this worked for me:

```
// add controllers with swagger
services.AddControllers(x => x.Conventions.Add(new ApiExplorerVersionConvention()))
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(x => { x.SuppressMapClientErrors = true; });
```

For more info for older .Net versions see here:

[Hide Swagger Bad Response for .net 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56341749/hide-swagger-bad-response-example-model-in-net-core-2-2)